# MySQL create table query

Tags: mysql, database

so i have the following query to create a table

```
create table teaches(
 course_id varchar(250), 
 foreign key(course_id) references course(course_id), 
 sec_id varchar(250), 
 foreign key(sec_id) references section(sec_id), 
 semester integer, 
 foreign key(semester) references section(semester) year integer, 
 foreign key(year) references section(year), 
 teacher_id varchar(250), 
 primary key(course_id, sec_id, semester, year, teacher_id)
);
```

the error that i am getting is:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'year integer, foreign key(year) references section(year), teacher_id varchar(250' at line 1

We were given the foreign and primary keys:

teaches (course_id, sec_id, semester, year, teacher_id)
Primary key: course_id, sec_id, semester, year, teacher_id
Foreign key: course_id, sec_id, semester, year
Foreign key: teacher_id

I think the problem might be with teacher_id but i am not sure how to approach this as teacher_id is only in this table and have no idea how to make it foreign in the same table. any help would be much appreciated.

I tried using the foreign key in the same table and referencing it back to the same table (teaches) but i am still getting the same error, i have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: If you read error message you'll see you are missing a comma right where the error message indicates.

Answer (score 0):

The `year` column is not properly separated from the previous line with a comma **`,`**. Just add a comma after `section(semester)`:

```sql
create table teaches(
 course_id varchar(250), 
 foreign key(course_id) references course(course_id), 
 sec_id varchar(250), 
 foreign key(sec_id) references section(sec_id), 
 semester integer, 
 foreign key(semester) references section(semester),
 year integer, 
 foreign key(year) references section(year), 
 teacher_id varchar(250), 
 primary key(course_id, sec_id, semester, year, teacher_id)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, i realized that and fixed it but still does not work,made some changes to the code:

create table teaches(course_id varchar(250)  NOT NULL, sec_id varchar(250) NOT NULL, semester integer NOT NULL, year integer NOT NULL, foreign key(sec_id, semester, year) references section(sec_id, semester, year), teacher_id integer, foreign key(teacher_id) references instructor(ID), primary key(course_id, sec_id, semester, year, teacher_id));

ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'teaches_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'section'